# how to set timer to awake method in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timer

I have an `-(IBAction)get;` its functionality is to awake some methods.

```
-(IBAction)get{
    [self msgToServer:@"MSRQ" Username:username];
        [self msgToServer:@"TRNR" Username:username];
        [self subscriptonList];
}
```

now i want to know that how can i set a timer in it? when user press "get" button it should call only `[self msgToServer:@"MSRQ" Username:username];` & after 5 seconds it should awake `[self msgToServer:@"TRNR" Username:username];` and after next 5 seconds it should awake `[self subscriptonList];` automatically.

i Hop question is understandable.
Note: I am working in Xcode, Objective-c
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of

```
[invocation performSelector:@selector(invokeMethod) withObject:object afterDelay:delay];
```

Or if you want a timer

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:inteval target:self selector:@selector(urMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES/NO];
```

If you want to use dummy methods

```
-(IBAction)get{
    [self msgToServer:@"MSRQ" Username:username];
    [self performSelector:@selector(sendMessage) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}
- (void)sendMessage
{
[self msgToServer:@"TRNR" Username:username];
[self performSelector:@selector(subscriptonList) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];

}
```

Comment: how much delay will give first one?

Comment: & how to pass the parameters in this way?

Comment: you can pass a single parameter using object field.

Comment: You can create a dummy method in your own class,and then call [self performSelector:@selector(method) withObject:object afterDelay:delay];

Comment: I m sorry for stupid questions infect i am very new in this field.
so plz tell am i right? [self performSelector:@selector(msgToServer) withObject:@"TRNR" afterDelay:5];
infect it is giving exception